# Android disable SMS service

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-broadcast

Is there a way to programatically disable the user from receiving/sending sms messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. Maybe on rooted devices etc you could, but it's not standard situation to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about sending part, but to block receiving sms you can give your app high priority

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and in your [BroadcastReceiver's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) onReceive() method, you can use [abortBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29). So that received sms doesn't reach inbox.